# kubernetes does not track pods success count for job completion

Tags: parallel-processing, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a job as defined [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/) i.e. "parallel processing using work queue"
on GKE

Each pod runs a single container and That container has an R script, takes around 5 mins to finish and then Pod completes successfully.

When I run the job for small numbers of completions like

```
completions: 606
parallelism: 450
backoffLimit: 1
```

Everything runs fine, Cluster scales up and down properly and Job gets finished.

But when I run the job with specifications like

```
completions: 37572
parallelism: 1610
backoffLimit: 1
```

> Pod succeeded count gets increased for a while but after that, it stays
>   in between 1000 to 1500 and never reach to completions

[image]

Though pods are completing successfully, I can see them on google cloud kubernetes dashboard and output files are also being generated successfully.
Queue is also showing the progress very accurately
[image]

And It has happened to me every time when I have run the job with high number of parallelism.
I have tried different autoscaling node pool setup in my cluster for machine type with 64-CPUs, 32-CPUs, 16-CPUs.

Currently, the way I am handling is
=> When queue has number of consumers == parallelism OR files_in_output == completions
=> I delete the job and delete the autoscaling node pool.

Please find the cluster details
[image]

Cluster status is always green during the run.

**QUESTION**

- Why job completion count never increase after a certain point (i.e in my case below my parallelism count)? Even though pods are finishing successfully.
- And the worst thing is the job completion count decreases too? That I can't even understand. What will be the reason that kubernetes is behaving like so?
- Do I need to add some additional fields to my spec template so that
  it tracks job completions properly?

Update:

- I have enough CPU Quota
- Each container(Pod) is limited to use 1 CPU and 1GB RAM.
- I have also upgraded cluster and node-pools to 1.10.6-gke.2 version. No Luck.

GKE ISSUE REPORTED => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114650730

**job.yml**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  # Unique key of the Job instance
  name: my-job
spec:
  completions: 37572
  parallelism: 1610
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-job
      labels:
        jobgroup: my-jobs
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: jobs-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fileserver-claim
          readOnly: false
      containers:
      - name: rscript
        image: gcr.io/project/image:v1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1000Mi
        env:
        - name: BROKER_URL
          value: amqp://user:pwd@rabbitmq-service:5672
        - name: QUEUE
          value: job-queue
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/work/output
          name: jobs-pv-storage
      # Do not restart containers after they exit
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: ever tried to click that "upgrade available" button? while most likely, those extreme values might just exceed the resources available to the cluster; add more nodes. stack-driver can filter per `pod_id`, which would provide a method to drill down, what the actual cause may be.

Comment: I will try upgrading GKE version. Thanks. I drilled down pods are running smoothly they also exit with proper status "completed".

Comment: @MartinZeitler RE: resources unavailable - I did an exercise where I limited autoscaling node to 4 and set parallelism to 450 and completion to 606 and things run fine - even though most of the pods are failing due to resources not available.

Comment: can you clarify the issue? Is the job not completing and just creating pods infinitely because it never reaches the completed threshhold? Or is the job reaching completion but is not reflected in the dashboard?

Comment: Hi @PatrickW, Updated my question. For me pods are finishing successfully but job completion count never increases after certain count (let's say 1500) and then it decreases (will go 1100) and then increase again (but does not go beyond my parallel count).  Because of that job never completes. So I had to verify it manually  (based on my output files and queue count in rabbitmq) and then I delete the job.

Comment: @PatrickW This doesn't happen when I go for short runs like 900 or 600 job completion

Comment: @PatrickW On job dashboard - pods are shown succeeded in pods list. Job dashboard or `kubectl get jobs` never provide correct succeeded pod count. And Job will run forever if one does not stop it

Comment: sounds like a bug :S I'd take what you have and open a public issue with Google

Comment: Thanks for the support @PatrickW. I will appreciate if you can link the issue URL in question.

Comment: You can open report this through Google's Public Issue Tracker [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: did you get any update on this @RahulGautam? I am having the same issue.

Comment: GKE team has started investigation 2 days ago, the issue reported by me is private now because of the same reason. @yigit I will update this thread as soon as I get some concrete answer. Thanks

Comment: @RahulGautam Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as Community Wiki.

As mentioned by @Rahul Gautam original issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114650730 is not visible as it contains some Private information. There is a new public issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172663707 which was closed as `Intended behavior`

In nutshell, this scenario is related with Pod Garbage Collector behavior.

Pod Garbage Collector interferes Job completion. Garbage Collector threshold is controlled by `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold` flag in `kube-controller-manager` as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/). Default value is `12500` and it's cluster wide so it counts all jobs in all namespaces.

```
--terminated-pod-gc-threshold int32     Default: 12500
Number of terminated pods that can exist before the terminated pod garbage collector starts deleting terminated pods. If <= 0, the terminated pod garbage collector is disabled.
```

Due to that fact, when number of jobs are lower than 12500 you will not experience this issue.

As a workaround you could change `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold` flag to not hit this threshold. However, in GKE controller manager is managed by Google, thus GKE users cannot change that value.

In addition, there is already an open [Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28486) about re-implementing this behavior.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing exactly the same behavior with 1700 number of completions. `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | wc -l` gives me 1098. So there is much less than 12500 pods in the cluster. But still, job pods are being garbage collected. Maybe this configuration setting were changed for GKE?